# getting the value of column inside a table using ajax in php codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, codeigniter

I have a simple shopping website in codeigniter in which I have an sql table like below:

[image]

So whenever a user selects a product size, I want to show how many pieces are left, so I took the following approach for this code:

```js
function checkstock() {

  var stockid = $(".stockid").val();
  var idp = $("#idp").val();
  var transfer = [stockid, idp];
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/homecontroller/checkstock",
    data: {
      result: JSON.stringify(transfer)
    },
    success: function(response) {
      if (response) {
        $('#msg').html('<span style="color: green;">ONLY ' + stockid + "</span>");

      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="idp" name="prodid" value="<?php echo $product->id;?>" type="hidden">
<input class="stockid" type="radio" onclick="checkstock();" name="size" value="xs">
<input class="stockid" type="radio" onclick="checkstock();" name="size" value="s">
<input class="stockid" type="radio" onclick="checkstock();" name="size" value="m">
```

Below is my controller's and view's code,

```html
  function checkstock(){
          $post = json_decode($_POST['result']);
          $idp = $post[1];
          $stockid = $post[0];
          $exists = $this->product->checkstock($idp,$exists);
          echo $exists;
  }
```

```
  function checkstock($idp,$stockid)
   {
        $this->db->select($stockid);
        $this->db->where('id', $idp);
        $this->db->from('product');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
   }
```

However this doesn't echo the count in the column, can anyone please tell me how to fix this, thanks in advance.

Comment: this line                     $exists = $this->product->checkstock($idp,$exists); in controller is                     $exists = $this->product->checkstock($idp,$stockid); . am not able to edit this post due to some technical error

Comment: Why don't you use the response here: `if (response) {$('#msg').html('<span style="color: green;">ONLY ' + stockid + "</span>")}`

Comment: @Canh i didnt get u bro

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(response)` to make sure it does not return anything?

Answer (score 0):

FROM

```
function checkstock($idp,$stockid)
{
    $this->db->select($stockid);
    $this->db->where('id', $idp);
    $this->db->from('product');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}
```

TO

```
function checkstock($idp,$stockid)
{
    $this->db->select($stockid);
    $this->db->where('id', $idp);
    $this->db->from('product');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result = $query->row();
    return $result->{$stockid};
}
```

Then you can get data into `reponse` variable and just `console` it.